# Android game countdown timers

Tags: android, timer

I am working on a game (my first) for Android. I want a function like a lot of games do where a "consumable" regenerates over time. I want to display the countdown timer for a +1 on the consumable. When it reaches 0, i want the timer to reset and start over, while the consumable increases by 1. If the consumable is at it's pre-defined max, I want the timer to stop until the consumable is used, then systematically start again.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   int currentConsumable = 2;
   int maxConsumable = 5;
   boolean isConsumableMaxed = false;
   long timeToAddConsumable; //unknown calculation for 10 minutes

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      TextView countDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDownDisplay);

      if (currentConsumable==maxConsumable) {
          isConsumableMaxed = true;
          //some function to stop the timer
      } else { isConsumableMaxed = false; }
          //function to begin countdown and setText to countDown's TextView


....

    }
}
```

What I am looking for assistance with is how to calculate the time I need (10 minutes - but i'd prefer the equation so I can change it without asking for the specific time again).

I would also like to know how to get a countdown to begin and display it on countDown, as well as how to cancel it when isConsumableMaxed == true.

Note - the countdown should continue when the game is closed.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.